# How do you leave a guild in Godville?

Tags: android, godville

Is it possible?  I want to leave the guild the game put me in and create my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can only join a guild after your hero reaches level 12. If you are already in a guild and want to join another one type in "leave guild and join "Guild Name" guild" (this works best when your hero is idle outside of town; do not cancel your current quest first).